# jquery Datepicker on clone rows

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

im using the Datepicker that comes with jquery...

**new.php**

```
<html>
<table id="testtable">
<tr id="table_row1">
<td><input type="text" name="date[]" class="pickDate"></td>
<td><?php ...some php stuff here...?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<label onclick="cloneRow('testtable','table_row1')"></label>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<php
include('new.php')
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pickDate').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

javascript function for cloning:

```
function cloneRow(tablename,rowname) {
var row = document.getElementById(rowname); // find row to copy
var table = document.getElementById(tablename); // find table to append to
var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

So the problem is, on the first row, the datepicker is there, and works, but if i clone the row, the cloned one has no datepicker.

I checked if the class gets cloned too, and yes it does.

Im very new to jquery, but does jquery maybe not notice that there has been added a new row?

How can i get this to work?

Comment: I think you have to run .each() method again after cloneRow function.

Comment: just copy and paste your $(".pickDate").each code which is under document.ready to at the end of your cloneRow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the code that applies the plugin is only ever run once, at page load. You'll need to apply the plugin each time you clone a node. Also, since you already have jQuery around, I modified the code to use jQuery to manipulate the elements.

```
function cloneRow(tablename,rowname) {
  var row = $("#" + rowname); // find row to copy
  var table = $("#" + tablename); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.clone(); // copy children too
  clone.attr("id", "newID"); // change id or other attributes/contents
  table.append(clone); // add new row to end of table
  clone.children(".pickDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
}
```

Comment: As long as jQuery has been included on the page prior to it being executed, yes. jQuery is just a javascript library ($ is actually just a function in the global scope), so you can use it just like any other piece of javascript.